# How would I reach the imageUrl

Tags: javascript

So I'm calling an API with node-fetch and I want to get the `imageUrl` part of the JSON how would I get there with `json.data.?`

```
{
 data: [
   {
     targetId: 8325785,
     state: 'Completed',
     imageUrl: 'imageUrl'
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: First access the object at index 0 of the `data` array, and then access the `imageUrl` property from that: `json.data[0].imageUrl`

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get by   `json.data[0].imageUrl` array first object and for all `imageUrl` you need `foreach` `loop`

```js
let obj ={
 data: [
   {
     targetId: 8325785,
     state: 'Completed',
     imageUrl: 'imageUrl'
   }
  ]
}

if(obj.data[0] !=undefined)
{
  console.log(obj.data[0].imageUrl);
}

obj.data.forEach(element => console.log(element.imageUrl));
```